# Change all integer columns to categories python

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], 'b' : [2,3,4,5,3], 'c': ['a','b','c','d','e']})
df

    a   b   c
0   0   2   a
1   1   3   b
2   1   4   c
3   1   5   d
4   0   3   e
```

Is there a simple way to turn all the integer columns to categories? I can do:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].astype('category')
```

for one column but how for all at once? In R I would just do:

```
df %>% mutate_if(is.integer, as.factor)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['int64']).astype('category')
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following:

```
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
df.select_dtypes(include=numerics).astype('category')
```

Another solution:

```
df._get_numeric_data().astype('category')
```

Comment: He says all *integer* columns.

Comment: I only want the integer columns converted

Comment: sorry i did not read the question fully. I have revised the solution. can you please check

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with `np.integer` for seelct all types integers columns and only selected columns set to `category`:

```
c = df.select_dtypes(np.integer).columns
df[c] = df[c].astype('category')
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  0  2  a
1  1  3  b
2  1  4  c
3  1  5  d
4  0  3  e

print (df.dtypes)
a    category
b    category
c      object
dtype: object
```